# How does one define font sizes in percentages in a WPF application for accessibility?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, accessibility, dpi

I am looking into adding accessibility support to a WPF application. This article describes guidelines for introducing accessibility support into an application:

[WPF Accessibility for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg712258.aspx)

In this article it states:

> WPF is dpi-aware, but you must still avoid hardcoding layouts, size, or font, and instead use percentages where possible to ensure the scaling works for all users.

How does one go about defining percentages on font sizes. I am thus far only familiar with defining styles, which have specific font sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that's just poor wording. All font sizes in WPF are specified in device-independent pixels or derivatives thereof. I really don't understand their point at all in the context given. Any explicit sizes on grids, for example, are also specified in DIPs.

What's important is that you consider and test what happens to your UI when there is extraneous or strained screen real-estate. Does it resize naturally and allow users to make the most of their space? Do any UI elements get cut off when the UI is shrunk? Are labels clipped when localized text is substituted?